# Angular - Constant Variable Decided Conditionally

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular app I have defined a constant such as:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTagsInput'])
   .constant('API', 'https://www.example.com/api/v1')
})();
```

However I want this API URL to be dependant on a constant I have set above, namely:

```
var WORKING_ON_ENV = "dev";
```

So I've tried to implement this using the following - however its not working - is this actually possible with Angular constants?:

```
.constant('API', function() {
  if (WORKING_ON_ENV == "prod") {
    return 'https://www.example.com/api/v1'
  } else {
    return 'https://www.example.com/api/v2'
  }
})
```

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a ternary:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTagsInput'])
   .constant('API', (WORKING_ON_ENV == "prod" ? 'https://www.example.com/api/v1' : 'https://www.example.com/api/v2'))
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

```
.constant('API', 
    (function() {
      if (WORKING_ON_ENV == "prod") {
        return 'https://www.example.com/api/v1'
      } else {
        return 'https://www.example.com/api/v2'
      }
    //Immediately invoke it
    })() 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code initializes the API constant to a function. What you want is to initialize it to the value returned by that function:

```
function getApi() {
  if (WORKING_ON_ENV == "prod") {
    return 'https://www.example.com/api/v1'
  } else {
    return 'https://www.example.com/api/v2'
  }
}

.constant('API', getApi());
```

But this can be inlined:

```
.constant('API', WORKING_ON_ENV == "prod" ? 'https://www.example.com/api/v1' : 'https://www.example.com/api/v2');
```